# How to implement UDP in Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, udp

I have implemented a web app with spring framework.
Now I need a udp server that receive incoming messages from clients (android devices).
How can I add this functionality into my spring based project?
Thanks.

Comment: Check out [Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/), in particular [TCP and UDP Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html). Hope this might help you.

Comment: I did. But I don't understand it very well. Could you provide some example or link please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the [TCP and UDP Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html) of [Spring Integration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/), supponing you just receive an UDP message and do something with that message, you should follow the next steps:

#### Create the message consumer

```
package com.example.udp;

import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

public class UDPConsumer {

    @Autowire what you want, this will be a Spring Bean

    @ServiceActivator
    public void consume(Message message) {
         ... do something with message ...
    }
}
```

#### Optional: create a udp-server.properties with some property

```
udp-server.threads=10
udp-server.port=4000
udp-server.buffer-size=500
...
```

#### Create the config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:int-ip="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ip/spring-integration-ip.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:udp-server.properties" />

    <bean id="udpConsumer" class="com.example.udp.UDPConsumer" />

    <int:channel id="inputChannel">
        <int:queue />
    </int:channel>

    <int-ip:udp-inbound-channel-adapter id="udpReceiver"
        channel="inputChannel"
        port="${udp-server.port}"
        pool-size="${udp-server.threads}"
        receive-buffer-size="${udp-server.buffer-size}"
        multicast="false"
        check-length="true"/>

    <int:service-activator input-channel="inputChannel"
        ref="udpConsumer" />

    <int:poller default="true" fixed-rate="500" />

</beans>
```

**Notes**: Spring Integration has a lot of interesting features, like message routing and transformation. I recommend to have an accurate look at the official documentation.